# Getting wrong image path in custom ModelForm saving

Tags: django, image, crop, django-forms

I'm using a django `ModelForm` to create a model instance by submitting a form including an image. Since I want to crop the image before saving, I've written custom save for the form. Here's the code:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    product = super(ProductForm, self).save(commit=False)    
    if self.cleaned_data['x'] is not None:
        x = self.cleaned_data['x']
        y = self.cleaned_data['y']
        x2 = self.cleaned_data['x2']
        y2 = self.cleaned_data['y2']            
        img = product.image
        try:
            box = (x, y, x2, y2)
        except:
            print("error!")
        try:
            # I'm getting wrong path here
            to_crop = Image.open(img.path)    
            cropped = to_crop.crop(box)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        cropped.save()    
    product.save()
```

Problem is, I'm getting wrong image path `product.image.path`. To be more clear, it's my image field in `Product` model:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="products", verbose_name=u'عکس', null=True, blank=True)
```

It's suppose to save the image in `media/products` folder and actually submitting the form saves the picture in right place, but when debugging, the value of `product.image.path` is **media/img.jpeg** not **media/products/img.jpeg**.

What's the problem? Can you help me please? Any recommendation about doing this task more efficient or better would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are assigning the ImageField again, after the upload. Check the following.
The `img.path` should give you the absolute path, and `img.url` will give you a relative path. To test your code, you may do something like this in you django shell:

```
>>> p = Person(name="Someone")
>>> p.image.save("myfile.jpg",File(open("img.jpg")),save=True)
```

You should import the model and also `from django.core.files import File`.
Now we have the image. Let's check the current `MEDIA_URL`:

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.MEDIA_URL
'media/'
```

Back to our image, the `path` and `url` should give you relative and absolute path:

```
>>> p.image.path
u'/programs/django/test/media/uploads/pictures/myfile.jpg'
>>> p.image.url
'media/uploads/pictures/myfile.jpg'
```

Now, let's check what happens if we assign something to `p.image` directly:

```
>>> p.image = "myfile.jpg"
>>> p.image.url
'media/myfile.jpg'
>>> p.image.path
u'/programs/django/test/media/myfile.jpg'
```

So, as you see, setting the p.image directly, would disregard `upload_to` field, and it doesn't create a new file.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a different `MEDIA_ROOT` on live and debug settings. If not, try debugging with

```
python manage.py runserver --verbosity=3
```

Comment: how can I find value of my `MEDIA_ROOT` in debug mode?